# dhtmlxScheduler with mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, dhtmlx

I have been trying to implement DhtmlxScheduler Standard Edition v.3.5 in to my mvc3 project.
Following the tutorial at http://www.dhtmlx.com/blog/?p=639

The tutorial is in mvc2 I believe and I am having a bit of trouble following it.

Here is my view page;

```
@*@Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>";*@

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head runat="server">
    <title>Index</title>

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/dhtmlxscheduler.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/dhtmlxscheduler.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 

    <style type="text/css">
        html, body
        {
            height:100%;
            padding:0px;
            margin:0px;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function init() {
            scheduler.init("scheduler_here", new Date(2010, 6, 1), "month");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
    <div id="scheduler_here" class="dhx_cal_container" style='width:100%; height:100%;'>
        <div class="dhx_cal_navline">
            <div class="dhx_cal_prev_button">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="dhx_cal_next_button">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="dhx_cal_today_button"></div>
            <div class="dhx_cal_date"></div>
            <div class="dhx_cal_tab" name="day_tab" style="right:204px;"></div>
            <div class="dhx_cal_tab" name="week_tab" style="right:140px;"></div>
            <div class="dhx_cal_tab" name="month_tab" style="right:76px;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="dhx_cal_header">
        </div>
        <div class="dhx_cal_data">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run this page with out the style-sheet it loads the calender but it is all over the place, so I add the CSS and them I get nothing??

Comment: What do you mean by nothing? Blank page? No events? Anything on the firebug console?

Answer (score 0):

What exactly goes wrong? This code will work in mvc3, except maybe that you should add @{Layout = null;} at the top of the page. Scheduler should occupy the whole size of its container, which is div#scheduler_here.
If you want scheduler to take only the part of the page, you can set sizes of "scheduler_here", eg <div id="scheduler_here" class="dhx_cal_container" style='width:960px;margin:0 auto;height:100%;'>
Hope it helps.